# PHP string with quotes, output into html table distorting layout

Tags: php, html, database, string, html-table

I'm writing a review script in PHP. The review text which the reviewer writes is inserted into a database along with other values such as the date and the title the reviewer gave to the review.

I want to output the review on a table on a separate page. I have written that already and it works fine except when the reviewer writes something like 'test'. So if there is a quotation mark or speech mark in the review, the table distorts and the review stays on one line and doesn't follow the width of the `<td>`

Here is the code:

```
    <?php


        echo "<tr $class>";
        echo "<td width='400' class='style1' style='color: #069; font-size: 15px;'>".$rating." &nbsp;&nbsp;&ldquo;".$row['title']."&rdquo; &nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td width='200' class='style1'><div align='left'>Reviewed ".date_format($timeCreate, 'j F Y ')."</div></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr $class>";
        echo "<td width='200'>";

        // Prints pros, cons, and other thoughts fields
        if($row['comment'])
        {

                echo "<p class='style2'>".$row['comment']."</p><div id='usname'>by ".$row['name']."<br><br></div><div class='$g'><font size='2' color='black'>Was this review helpful?</font>&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Yes' onClick = 'myCall()' style='background-color:#556B2F;color:white;padding:2px; cursor:pointer' name='help' id='$g' class='button' /></div></td><td><img src='Themes/images/glyphicons_072_bookmark.png' width='10' height='15'></div><font size='1' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['helpful']." found this helpful</font><div id='mybox'>

        </div></td>";
            echo '

    '; 
        }
        echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>";


        echo "<tr $class>";

        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "</tr>";

    }

    echo ""; 
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "<p class='red'>Error</p>";
    echo "<p>This person does not exist.</p>";
}
?>
```

The table looks like this:

```
<table width='600' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
```

There is more code above which outputs data like the review title but I did not include that as I don't think it is that important.

It is not just the review script which has this issue, it is all tables where information from the database is being placed into a table.

Comment: Could you please illustrate the problem? A screenshot would be nice. Better yet a link to a live demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Could you please post the result where table is breaking.

Comment: You should specify `px` for your widths heights and borders, etc. e.g., `400px`

Comment: The table is breaking at `echo "<p class='style2'>".$row['comment']."</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If text is going to be displayed, you need to convert special characters to html entities. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This will convert & to `&amp;` and " to `&quot;`

If you need single quotes converted, then use the ENT_QUOTES option.

Comment: still get the same problem. I did this: `$com = $row['comment'];
              $com1 = htmlentities($com, ENT_QUOTES);
                echo "<p class='style2'>$com1</p>`

Comment: I see no problem with that

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem in below code snippet

```
echo "<td width='200'>";
        // Prints pros, cons, and other thoughts fields
        if($row['comment'])
        {

                echo "<p class='style2'>".$row['comment']."</p><div id='usname'>by ".$row['name']."<br><br></div><div class='$g'><font size='2' color='black'>Was this review helpful?</font>&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Yes' onClick = 'myCall()' style='background-color:#556B2F;color:white;padding:2px; cursor:pointer' name='help' id='$g' class='button' /></div></td><td><img src='Themes/images/glyphicons_072_bookmark.png' width='10' height='15'></div><font size='1' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['helpful']." found this helpful</font><div id='mybox'>

        </div></td>";
            echo '

    '; 
        }
        echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>";
```

If comments are set, then you are adding two columns, but if comments are not set, then it will open a TD and then just close TR. This may cause in unformatted HTML. Can you please add a else condition and check, like below

```
echo "<td width='200'>";

        // Prints pros, cons, and other thoughts fields
        if($row['comment'])
        {

                echo "<p class='style2'>".$row['comment']."</p><div id='usname'>by ".$row['name']."<br><br></div><div class='$g'><font size='2' color='black'>Was this review helpful?</font>&nbsp;<input type='submit' value='Yes' onClick = 'myCall()' style='background-color:#556B2F;color:white;padding:2px; cursor:pointer' name='help' id='$g' class='button' /></div></td><td><img src='Themes/images/glyphicons_072_bookmark.png' width='10' height='15'></div><font size='1' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['helpful']." found this helpful</font><div id='mybox'>

        </div></td>";
            echo '

    '; 
        }
        else
        {
             echo "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr><tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this still did not work. I do not need the if statement there, is there a way to solve it without using the if statement?

Answer (score -3):

Mayby you should use addslashes()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

and later before displaying it stripcslashes()

Comment: How would that help, exactly?